# Angular form submission causes page to reload (production only)

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form that looks like

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)" 
      #myForm="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field" [(ngModel)]="field" name="field">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am importing `FormsModule` in my module and when the code is built for development everything works as expected. When I build the project for production the page reloads and no console log is provided.

I tried providing `$event` to the submit handler and explicitly stopping the default behavior (which is something `ngSubmit` should take care of implicitly as far as I know), but that didn't help.

The package versions are following

```
+-- @angular/animations@5.1.2
+-- @angular/cdk@5.0.2
+-- @angular/cli@1.6.1
+-- @angular/common@5.1.2
+-- @angular/compiler@5.1.2
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@5.1.2
+-- @angular/core@5.1.2
+-- @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.12
+-- @angular/forms@5.1.2
+-- @angular/http@5.1.2
+-- @angular/language-service@5.1.2
+-- @angular/material@5.0.2
+-- @angular/platform-browser@5.1.2
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.1.2
+-- @angular/router@5.1.2
+-- @types/jasmine@2.5.54
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
+-- @types/node@6.0.95
+-- codelyzer@4.0.2
+-- core-js@2.5.3
+-- jasmine-core@2.6.4
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.1.1
+-- karma@1.7.1
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.1.1
+-- karma-cli@1.0.1
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@1.3.1
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.1
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
+-- protractor@5.1.2
+-- rxjs@5.5.6
+-- ts-node@3.2.2
+-- tslint@5.7.0
+-- typescript@2.4.2
`-- zone.js@0.8.18
```

When I checked a project I worked on a little while ago, it uses the very same code and the application doesn't face this issue. Is there perhaps something, that should be done differently in new version of Angular?

**Edit:** When I made the changes suggested in comments which were

- Change the button type to `button`
- Explicitly call the submit handler from button click

The page still reloads and it's caused by checking form validity.

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
  if (form.form.invalid)
    return;
}
```

This is not the original cause as removing the validity check without making the proposed changes doesn't stop the page from reloading.

**Edit2:** So it indeed seems to be a package version problem. Here is [git project](https://gitlab.com/pikausp/forms-submission) that demonstrates the problem. With the default packages the issue didn't occure and it appeared once I updated the packages.

Comment: Change button type to button `<button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>`

Comment: @echonax the submit handler doesn't get called anymore

Comment: Ah, you have to add a click action like `(click)="onSubmit(myForm)"`. But it's been a while since I checked the latest FormsModule, don't know if it will work

Comment: Now I'm back to the page reloading. `type="button"` and calling handler manually as instructed by you

Comment: Ok the reload is now caused by checking form validity. Updating the question.

Comment: Have you tried passing `$event` and using `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @AJT_82 yes I did, with no result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also having the same issue. Apparently there is a bug already registered under Angular project. [Issue 21173](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21173).

I was able to get it working by making the change as per @thekiba

> // file:
>   /node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/production.js
>
> -mangle: true
>   +mangle: false

and ran the following command to build:

```
ng build --prod --env=release --aot --build-optimizer true --output-hashing all --extract-css true --named-chunks false --sourcemaps false
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much. I decided to go with @julianobrasil's answer as it feels less hacky. Using the previous version of uglify fixes the problem.

Comment: @pikausp they have released a new angular cli version: @angular/cli@1.6. I believe that has patched the issue.